# Is it possible to pass Id from aura:iteration to an already-rendered force:recordEdit?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, aura

Please excuse what is an undoubtedly rugged approach to this - I'm picking up aura :)

What I'm attempting is to have an `aura:iteration` iterate over a list of records, and when a single record in that iteration is clicked, open up a previously hidden `force:recordEdit` component to modify that record's values, so my question is this - **is there a way to use `indexVar` to pass the Id to the `force:recordEdit`?**

Is this even the right way to approach this? I've seen some other posts here that use child components.

Component markup:

```
<div id="editPanel" style="display:none;">
    <force:recordEdit aura:id="edit" recordId="**insert the Id from the iterator here**" />
    <button onclick="{!c.save}">Save</button> 
</div>

<aura:iteration items="{!v.parameters}" var="currParam" indexVar="index">
    {!currParam.Name}
    <lightning:button label="Edit" onclick="{!c.showEditPanel}"/>
</aura:iteration>
```

Controller snippet:

```
showEditPanel : function(component, event, helper) {
    document.getElementById("editPanel").style.display = "block";
},
save : function(component,event, helper){
   component.find("edit").get("e.recordSave").fire();
   document.getElementById("editPanel").style.display = "none";
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a good candidate for making use of a HTML5 data attribute. You'll be able to pass the current iteration's record ID through to the client-side controller on click, and then store that value in a Component Attribute (let's call this "currentRecordId"). This way, as long as your force:recordEdit's recordId is set to "{!v.currentRecordId}", it'll always show the last record you clicked on.

Comment: Thank you! I followed your advice and it's working as intended with one minor hiccup, I'm going to be posting a new follow up question, but this did answer my question!